# d3 redraw force directed graph with ajax returned data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I visualize the social network with D3.js's force directed graph. At First, I draw the graph with a json file. And then, use ajax to generate new json data. I want to redraw the graph with the new json data. I do as follows:

```
    var github = d3.select("#github").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    var twitter = d3.select("#twitter").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

    function draw(error, graph, svg, ico){//...}

    d3.json("/static/data/github.json", function(error, graph){draw(error, graph, github, github_ico)});
    d3.json("/static/data/twitter.json", function(error, graph){draw(error, graph, twitter, twitter_ico)});
```

The code above run when the page first load. And then, generate the new data with ajax as follows:

```
    $("button").click(function(events){

        events.preventDefault();

        $.post("/uir", $("form").serialize(), 

            function(data, status){

                d3.selectAll("svg").remove();

                var github = d3.select("#github").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
                var twitter = d3.select("#twitter").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

                d3.json("/static/data/github.json", function(error, graph){draw(error, graph, github, github_ico)});
                d3.json("/static/data/twitter.json", function(error, graph){draw(error, graph, twitter, twitter_ico)});
    });
```

});

The method I use is to remove svg from dom, and then redraw it with new data. But the browser didn't refresh to show the new graph.

The demo is on http://blog.stamaimer.com:5000